# How to determine if the relationships in an entity collection have been saved to the database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a situation where I'm adding **existing** entities to an entity collection. Before calling "context.SaveChanges()", I need to know which entities in the entity collection have **not** had their **relationship** saved in the database. There's no point in checking the "EntityState" property of each entity in the collection because they are all "Unchanged" (remember, the entities already exist in the database).  I should mention that the type of relationship is "many-to-many"...basically, I want to know if a row has been added to the "many-to-many" relationship table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to accomplish just that what you ask, but it may be of help - you can see which entities have been changed by inspecting contents of DBContext.ChangeTracker.Entries(), where every entry has reference to the changed entity object.
This collection should contain all new/modified/deleted records in any, including your many-to-many relationship table.

Comment: Thanks, Goran, for your suggestion.  I performed a test by adding an entity to the entity collection and then checked the following values:  [1] DbContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Count = 1 and   
[2] DbContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).First().IsRelationship = true    
The problem is that I still don't know which entities are involved in the relationship.  I think we're on the right track with your suggestion of using "DbContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries".  Does anyone know where we can go from here?

Comment: ObjectState entry in codefirst has Entity property, which is dbrow in question.

Comment: Thanks again, Goran, for your help with this problem.  I got the following: hbe.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).First().Entity = null.  It appears that the "Entity" property is null.  I guess that this makes sense because it seems that Entity Framework does not create an entities for the rows in a many-to-many relationship table.

Comment: One more thing you can check - Entry.CurrentValues - best to inspect in debugger, maybe it contains what you need.

Comment: You did it!! =)  I was able to retrieve the unique ID of the entity with the following: ((EntityKey)DbContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).First().CurrentValues[1]).EntityKeyValues[0].Value.  This is absolutely fantastic!  Thanks again, Goran, for all your help...it's very much appreciated!